# Master method - Analysis

Tags: algorithm, analysis, master-theorem

This is about analysis of algorithms:
Say, the running time of a problem is:

```
T(n) = { 1, for n == 1 | T(n/3) + THETA(1), for n > 1}
```

Now, this is `THETA(log base3 n)`

But, if I use Master Method, I evaluate to `THETA(log base2 n)`, using Case II

How am I supposed to get the correct answer from master method?

Comment: THETA(log base3 n) is equal to THETA(log base2 n)

Comment: How is that possible? An algorithm dividing problem into one-third of the original problem is faster that the one dividing into half. So, THETA(log base2 n) is slower that THETA(log base3 n).

Comment: @jaskirat: Yes, but only by a constant factor. THETA doesn't care about those.

Comment: Okay, so for big enough n, THETA(log base3 n) boils down to THETA(log base2 n). Is this right?

Comment: Not just for big enough n. For all n, log base 3 n = k * (log base 2 n) where k = 1 / log base 2 3 which is constant with respect to n.

Comment: So that implies THETA( log base(any number) n) is equal to (log base2 n) (For this problem statement). Meaning even if the original problem is halved or one-third or even one-tenth, the running time remains THETA(log base2 n). Great. Thanks.

Comment: @jaskirat: Yes, the base doesn't matter, so we usually just say THETA(log n).

Comment: But for these questions, is saying Big-oh(log base3 n) correct? That is a loose bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're the same. For any two bases `a` and `b`, `Θ(loga n) = Θ(logb n)`, so we usually don't mention the base at all and just say `Θ(log n)`.

This is because `loga n = (1 / logb a) * logb n`, so they differ by a factor of `1 / logb a` which is constant with respect to `n`.

Comment: But we do use bases in Big-oh, right? So, Big-oh(log base2 n) is different from Big-oh(log base3 n)?

Comment: The same argument works for `O(log n)`. It's still a constant factor and those disappear with Big-O as well.